# Mock inner Flurl HTTP client calls in REST API for testing

Tags: c#, .net, http, mocking, flurl

The goal is to test REST API that makes another http calls inside by mocking these inner calls.

There are 2 Flurl HTTP clients:

1. One is in an integration test that makes calls to the REST API - **testHttpClient**
2. And one is in REST API that makes calls to another API - **innerHttpClient**

I was trying to mock the calls in the tests according to the [Flurl HTTP documentation](https://flurl.dev/docs/testable-http/). Unfortunately, it seems only calls from **testHttpClient** are mocked. Setup rules are not working for **innerHttpClient**.

Any recommendations?

Comment: Read [this issue](https://github.com/tmenier/Flurl/issues/683) carefully. I suspect it's related to what you're trying to do, in which case you'll need to wait a bit for the fix in 4.0.